# Multi-index combined reverse cumsum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to sum over all remaining entries in a 2-d phase space. For a case where I have a 2d multi-index and I want to get the cumsum over each v1 individually, doing the below will suffice:

```
df['output'] = df.loc[::-1].groupby(['v1'])['value'].cumsum()[::-1]
```

| v1 | v2 | value | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 1. | 2. |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1. |
| 2 | 1 | 1. | 3. |
| 2 | 2 | 1. | 2. |
| 2 | 3. | 1. | 1. |
| 3 | 1 | 1. | 3. |
| 3 | 2 | 1. | 2. |
| 3 | 3 | 1. | 1. |

But I'd like to instead integrate over `v1` and `v2` simultaneously. e.g. if `v1=2` and `v2=3`, I'd like the result (`v1=2` & `v2=3`) + (`v1=3` & `v2&3`). Or for the same table, the desired result:

| v1 | v2 | value | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 | 1. | 6. |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 3. |
| 2 | 1 | 1. | 6. |
| 2 | 2 | 1. | 4. |
| 2 | 3. | 1. | 2. |
| 3 | 1 | 1. | 3. |
| 3 | 2 | 1. | 2. |
| 3 | 3 | 1. | 1. |

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I am not sure what is happening but seems to be `(df.v1 *df.v2)[::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your exact requirements, but to do this within the data frame, it is best just to iterate over each row and sum over the values in the rows whose indices are greater than the index values, respectively, for the row:

```
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[i, 'output'] = df.loc[(df.v2 >= row.v2) & (df.v1 >= row.v1), 'value'].sum()
```

For the data frame given, this produces the expected result:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                       'v2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                       'value': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[i, 'output'] = df.loc[(df.v2 >= row.v2) & (df.v1 >= row.v1), 'value'].sum()

    print(df)

        v1  v2  value  output
     0   1   1      1     9.0
     1   1   2      1     6.0
     2   1   3      1     3.0
     3   2   1      1     6.0
     4   2   2      1     4.0
     5   2   3      1     2.0
     6   3   1      1     3.0
     7   3   2      1     2.0
     8   3   3      1     1.0
```

Note that iterating over rows here is just as efficient (if not more) than calling `groupby` and `cumsum`. A better approach is to think of this as lower-triangular (sub) 2-D arrays in `numpy` and performing sum operations on those.